# Cplex Error : Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform

Tags: java, eclipse, dll

Please anyone help me out on this Cplex Error as early as possible ......

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\CPLEX_Studio124\cplex\bin\x86_win32\cplex124.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
java.library.path must point to the directory containing the CPLEX shared library
try invoking java with java -Djava.library.path=...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: ilog.cplex.Cplex.CPXopenCPLEX([I)J
    at ilog.cplex.Cplex.CPXopenCPLEX(Native Method)
    at ilog.cplex.CplexI.init(CplexI.java:5722)
    at ilog.cplex.CplexI.(CplexI.java:611)
    at ilog.cplex.IloCplex.(IloCplex.java:10384)
    at Sample1.main(Sample1.java:12)

When i run java program with Cplex i get the above error.......and i have written the java code in Eclipse IDE...

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are trying to use a 32-bit library with a 64-bit JRE. I don't think you can do that with [WoW64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64) or other multi-arch implementations (like on Linux). Instead, you could use a 64-bit version of cplex_studio **or** you could get a 32-bit version of the JRE to run it with your 32-bit version of cplex_studio.